# Basic SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I want to learn SharePoint.  But I do not know how to obtain the SharePoint foundation.  I did research to find out that the SharePoint foundation comes with servers for free, but which one?  What do I buy to obtain the basic version of SharePoint?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your OS and choice. You can install [SharePoint Foundation 2010](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24983)  on following OS `Windows Server 2008 R2, Windows Server 2008 Service Pack 2, Windows Server 2012` and on Windows 7 and [SharePoint Foundation 2013](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42039) on windows `Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1, Windows Server 2012, Windows Server 2012 R2`.

If you have Windows OS cals(license) then you dont need extra license for the sharepoint foundation as it is covered under os. check this one: [What are the licensing requirements to implement SharePoint Foundation in an extranet environment?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/13153/what-are-the-licensing-requirements-to-implement-sharepoint-foundation-in-an-ext)

Answer (score 0):

Here are the best link to approaching to SharePoint for newbie:

http://sharepoint-tutorial.net/

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj937861.aspx

http://www.goodreads.com/shelf/show/sharepoint

http://blog.pentalogic.net/2012/05/10-things-developers-should-know-about-sharepoint/

http://www.sharepointvn.net/all/

http://blog.furuknap.net/become-a-sharepoint-professional-key-questions-to-ask-part-1-discipline